# Object loaded successfully but not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js

i'm using Nuxtjs + Threejs. Default script from the website shows the `geometry` and the animation properly. I want to use custom model so i install `OBJLoader` and `MTLLoader` using `npm`, the packages installed successfully. 
template:

```
<template>
  <div id="three" class="three">

  </div>
</template>
```

Script code:

```
<script>
import * as Three from 'three'
import { MTLLoader, OBJLoader } from 'three-obj-mtl-loader'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      camera: null,
      scene: null,
      renderer: null,
      mesh: null,
      mtl: null,
      obj: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
        let container = document.getElementById('three')

        this.camera = new Three.PerspectiveCamera(70, container.clientWidth/container.clientHeight, 0.01, 10)
        this.camera.position.z = 1

        this.scene = new Three.Scene()
        this.mtl = new MTLLoader()
        this.obj = new OBJLoader()

        this.mtl.load('/mesh/sources/Coffee Hot Cup Sketchfab.mtl', (materials) => {
          materials.preload()
          this.obj.setMaterials(materials)
          this.obj.load('/mesh/sources/Coffee Hot Cup Sketchfab.obj', (object) => {
            this.scene.add(object)
          })
        })

        this.renderer = new Three.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true})
        this.renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight)
        this.renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 )
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
        container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)

    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.init()
  }
}
</script>
```

The problem is, when i want to use my custom model the object is not showing but it says the object loaded successfully. I don't know, if its from the path it should be showing not found error but its not. How do i fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I would always always use under bars "_" instead of spaces. I'm not sure that will fix, but at least if you try it, it would remove one bug case.

Comment: @JasonFoglia i changed it using `-`, but nothing changes..

Comment: What is in the dev tools console?

Comment: are you sure the camera is pointing at it? are you sure you are not zoomed in too much? also there are no lights in the code you posted.

Comment: @RandyCasburn `THREE.WebGLRenderer 100` and `OBJLoader: 562.817138671875ms`, nothing else..

Comment: @gaitat i'm using default camera, no changes on it.. Does the light affected? Because the default script not using the light too

Comment: @RandyCasburn i'm looking out at vue dev in `renderer` written `unknown component`. Is it the problem?

Comment: Most likely. If you want to spin up your Vue app in the playground we can take a closer look: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: @RandyCasburn https://codesandbox.io/embed/yqvkq2jzqz

Comment: @RandyCasburn any clue?

Comment: sorry for delay  - I don't get paid for this - but I have no clue. Everything looks correct, but Vue is not rendering the canvas. Sorry I cannot help.

Comment: canvas is there, although its empty.
<canvas width="611" height="1217" style="width: 611px;height: 1217px;"></canvas>

Comment: it has something to do with your object because if you add `this.scene.add( new Three.Mesh( new Three.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ), new Three.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } )));` and you change  `this.camera.position.z = 10;` it renders just fine.

Comment: @RandyCasburn but if i'm using the geometry from default tutorial it work perfectly

Comment: @Aldarund yaa, we can see the canvas but not the object :(

Comment: @gaitat as i said, if its using default geometry it just fine.. But when i want to change to my custom model it shows nothing.. I tried to test my object from `3dviewer.net` and it work but no in my page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys! I fixed this using `vue-3d-model` framework. I've found that `obj-mtl-loader` has no longer updates so its old..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set the material to be double-sided. I had similar problem with Unity game engine. Sometimes the loaded files were missing some textures. Making sure of double-sidedness of my object materials usually helped!